# MFC Feature Pack: Re-show classic Menu under XP

Tags: menu, mfc, windows-xp, mfc-feature-pack

We ported our program to use MFC Feature Pack. The problem is that the menu bar is not visible when Windows XP is used. (With Windows 7 it works.) This seems to be a known problem and a codeproject article recommends using CMFCMenuBar. But we don't like that option because we have a custom menu with lots of custom program code.

Is there are way to show the "classic" menu under XP?

Comment: I use the CMFCMenubar and I have lots of custom menu items added and deleted on runtime through OnInitMenuPopup.

Comment: But if you really want to skip menu creation on XP, you have to detect if you are on XP (I don´t know how) and skip the lines: if (!m_wndMenuBar.Create(this))
{
m_wndMenuBar.SetPaneStyle(m_wndMenuBar.GetPaneStyle() | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_ALIGN_TOP);
DockPane(&m_wndMenuBar);
}
in that case